# Dynamic prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have prepared query like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT instr FROM raspisanie WHERE state='1' AND type!='free' AND instr=? AND school=? AND age=? AND startdate > NOW()");
```

And bind like this:

```
$stmt->bind_param("sis", $get_instr, $get_school, $get_age);
```

The problem is that all variables are optional. So in case if at least one variable is empty, database will return nothing. I think that somehow i have to make this statement dynamic (to exclude disbalance between prepared and binding params), but how no idea how to do it.

So i have to make dynamic both prepare and bind params? What is right way to do it? All variables are being catched by GET from the form on the site.

Comment: if they're all optional and you're using them in a query, then they should all have a default value.

Comment: This is good idea, but doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well i found the solution. This is something that works perfect for me

```
$sql = "SELECT instr FROM schedule WHERE state=1 AND type!='free' AND startdate > NOW()";

$school=$_GET['school'];
$age=$_GET['age'];
$instrument=$_GET['instrument'];

if ($school==true)
{
$sql .= " AND school=?";
$bind[]=$school;
$type[0]='i';
}

if ($age==true)
{
$sql .= " AND (age=? OR mode='ind')";
$bind[]=$age;
$type[0].='s';
}

if ($instrument==true)
{
$sql .= " AND instr=?";
$bind[]=$instrument;
$type[0].='s';
}

$params=array_merge($type, $bind);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($instr);
$stmt->close();
```